# Redirecting after form submission with user input in the URL

Tags: php, forms, submit

I need to have a form that when filled out will create a variable and then goto a url with that variable in the url.

Something like this (but that works) :)

```
<form action="?????" method="?????">

Number: <input type="text" name="url1" value=""><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Goto URL">
</form>
```

When the submit is pressed I need it to goto http://somewhere.com?url=VALUEHERE

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use `method="GET"` to place the variables in the url:

```
<form action="http://somewhere.com/" method="GET">
    Number: <input type="text" name="url" value="" /><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Goto URL" />
</form>
```

Posting this form will go to http://somewhere.com/?url=USER_INPUT_URL

Comment: by the way you are missing  submit button or `document.name.submit()`

Comment: @Sourav: Updated with complete form.

Answer (score -1):

```
<form>
Number: <input type="text" name="url1" id="url1" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Goto URL" onclick="redirect()">
</form>

<script>
function redirect()
{
  window.location='http://somewhere.com?url=' + document.getElementByID('url1').value;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Different from 1st. No form needed, add an attribute named 'id' for the textfield,then defined a javascript function to retrieve the value of textfield,then do the jump, Hope usefully.

```
<form action="?????" method="?????">

Number: <input id="url1" type="text" name="url1" value=""><br>

<input type="button" name="submit" value="gotoURL()">
</form>

<script>
function gotoURL(){
window.location='http://somewhere.com?url='+document.getElementById('url1').value;
}
</script>
```